# Autogenerating XML comments in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

I have recently moved over to coding from c#.net in vb.net

In c# i could hit `///` above any class/method and Visual Studio would automaticly generate the xml comments body for me.

Example

```
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bar"></param>
        void foo(string bar)
        {

        }
```

How do I get this same behaviour in my vb.net project

I have tried `'''` and enter or space but it does nothing.
I'm using the same IDE for both projects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set "Generate XML documentation file" in Project menu, click Properties, Compile page. Then entering ''' will work.

Answer (score 2):

simply press ' button 3 times ie '''

Answer (score 0):

As I read this and wondered why it didn't work for me as the above explained was already checked for C#.

What I didn't realize is that this seems to work for Visual Basic as well. I unchecked that options and rechecked it and it worked.

If you install any plug in's that may allow snippets or code function automation may effect this as I have Code Rush installed for VB refactoring and it might have overrode my settings but it is fixed now.